# Не реагирует на условие MYSQL запрос

Tags: mysql

Есть mysql запрос:

```
mysql_query("
 SELECT * 
 FROM   notifications 
 INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.vk_id = notifications.from 
 INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.vk_id = notifications.to 
 WHERE notifications.npoints > 0 
   AND notifications.history = 1 
   AND (notifications.to = 1 OR notifications.from = 1) 
 ORDER BY notifications.id DESC LIMIT 5
");
```

На данную строку не реагирует. Всегда обращает внимание только на from. Хотя ведь написано: to или from:

```
notifications.to = 1 OR notifications.from = 1
```

Comment: А по конкретнее? Приведите пример данных и пример выборки.
У вас задача на условие какое?

Comment: @Чад, зачем Вам это? Мне просто нужно корректное условие.

Comment: Чтобы понять что у вас не так. Или вы действительно думаете что MySQL делает что то не то?
Скорее всего у вас расхождение в понимании задачи с её реализацией.
Хотя в принципе мне по барабану. Не у меня же запрос не отрабатывает :-)

Comment: А что значит "не реагирует". users.vk_id = 1 выбирается только один раз? Или что? А может отсеянные записи не удовлетворяют другим условиям?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пробуйте, и на будущее, чтобы зарезервированые слова использовать в кач-ве названия полей обрамляйте их символом `в вашем случае`notifications`.`from`

```
mysql_query("
 SELECT * 
 FROM   `notifications` 
 INNER JOIN `users` u1 ON u1.`vk_id` = `notifications`.`from` 
 INNER JOIN `users` u2 ON u2.`vk_id` = `notifications`.`to` 
 WHERE `notifications`.`npoints` > 0 
   AND `notifications`.`history` = 1 
   AND (`notifications`.`to` = 1 OR `notifications`.`from` = 1) 
 ORDER BY `notifications`.`id` DESC LIMIT 5
");
```

Answer (score 1):

вообще не понятно, зачем здесь inner join ? При таких критериях поиска они не нужны.

Может таки нужно проверять:

`.. AND (u1.vk_id = 1 OR u2.vk_id = 1)` ?

**Вы уверены что при to=1 notifications.npoints > 0 и notifications.history = 1 ?**

Comment: По поводу условия запроса - совершенно однохренственно. 

А джоин надо видимо чтобы выдрать данные по юзерам

Comment: хмм, пропала часть сообщения. 
Вы уверены что при to=1 
notifications.npoints > 0 и notifications.history = 1  ?

Comment: @shurik, да, уверен. И почему Вы опять про to? Он должен или по to или по from.